# Android - get the activity result when the calling activity finished

Tags: android

is there a way to get result from activity to one activity before the calling activity becuse the calling activity have noHistory attribute and the back button passing me to the one before?!

thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't have source activity the calling activity is finished! does the result goes back to the acivity before even it is not the calling one?!?!

Comment: can you explain it more? or have you found the answer?

Comment: let's say i'm in A activity and calling B activity the B activity calling to C activity and finish() so after pressing back button the B activity is no more in the stack history and there for i'm again in A activity. all i want is that A activty will reciave the result form C activity

Answer (score 1):

This is a decently short explanation of how the Activity result process works:

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html

Look for the "Starting Activities and Getting Results" heading under the Activity documentation in the stock Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes obvious you just need to start the new activity by using [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

[Here](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Android-Activity-startActivityForResult-387002) is the full description for the implementation of this method.

**Brief Description:**
You just need to start the target activity by using `startActivityForResult()` method same as we do by using `startActivity()`. Now it will redirect you in target activity, residing inside it, do all the processes and at the end just call `setResult()` method. So it will again get back to you in Source activity. Inside this you need to override the `onActivityResult()` method. Here you get the result from target activity.

Comment: I don't have source activity the calling activity is finished! does the result goes back to the acivity before even it is not the calling one?!?!

Answer (score 0):

StartActivityForResult()

Android Developer - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Example - http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html